# Workbook name changes, how change / adjust it in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

This macro uses a workbook name, but it changes sometimes. 
Is it possible to ignore it or adjust a different name? I tried to add it as string, but looks like I need something different.

```
Dim planavimas As String
planavimas = ActiveSheet.Name
Windows("Gamyba.xlsx").Activate
Range("A6:Y36").Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("PlanavimasET-19-01.xlsm").Activate  ' << (this workbook name changes) 
Range("B4").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Set a reference when you open it?

Comment: Firstly, you should avoid `Select` `Activate` `ActiveSheet` etc ( [see here for help on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) ). Secondly, don't use `Windows` to access the workbook.  If the code is in the workbook you want, use `ThisWorkbook`. If your code opens the workbokk, set a reference when it does so.  If there is a pattern to the name, loop the `Application.Workbooks` collection and check for that pattern.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I deleted first two code lines and used Chris Neilsen suggestion - ThisWorkbook. It works fine, simple and effective.